# How to label arrows tips?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to label arrow tips in the following code:

```
    \documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
    \draw [{Circle[]}-{Circle[]}] (0,0) node {text} -- ++(1,0)  -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- 
    ++ (1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1,0);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\draw [{Circle[]}-{Circle[]}] (0,0) node[left] {text} -- ++(1,0)  -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- 
++ (1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(-1,0) node[left] {more text};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]